# Is there a way to use nested styles as a mixin in Sass or Less?

Tags: css, sass, less, mixins, nested

Is it possible to use a set of nested styles as a mixin in either Sass or Less?

For instance in Less:

```
.class {
  margin:10px;
    ul {
      list-style:none;
        li {
          padding:5px;
        }
     }
  }
```

Then call that whole block as a mixin like:

```
.other-class {
  .class;
}
```

I know what I just demo'd doesn't work. I'm wondering if there is a way that does. Thanks!

Comment: >I know what I just demo'd doesn't work. - Actually it does in Less.

Comment: If my answer doesn't help, please post the HTML you're using with this.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation of either preprocessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

This works fine in less (without any modifications) because you can simply write the name of a class to include it.

However, for scss, you will have to change `.class;` to `@extend .class;`. After that change, the scss version will also work as expected.

Comment: Weird, I was having problems with it compiling. Now it works perfect. Must've missed something simple. I guess we're good, now. Thanks for the answers.